# Sandwich Theorem not working?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> This is the limit I need to solve:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4 \cos(n) - 3n^2)(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4}$$

I simplified it to this:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(4 \cos(n) - 3n^2)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))}.$$
At this point I want to use the Sandwich Theorem on the Numerator and Denominator to evaluate the limit.

I use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{b} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} a}{\lim_{n \to \infty} b}$ when  $b\ne 0$.

By the Sandwich Theorem both the Numerator and Denominator is $\infty$.
Hence the answer is 1.

But if I calculate the limit whole without splitting it into two I get $\frac{3}{2}$. Which answer is correct? Please Help!

Comment: You cannot 'divide' infinity by infinity. It is not defined.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that I did that! The fraction is definitely undefined. So we need to apply the Theorem to the whole expression.

Comment: Your "simplification" is also not correct. You "trade" $n^5$ for $n^4$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just noticed that I wrote the wrong LaTeX formula. It should actually be: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4 \cos(n) - 3n)^2(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}$

Comment: And hence the simplification: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2(4 \cos(n) - 3n)^2}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))}$

Comment: Could you please recommend what I should do with question? Editing would make the wonderful answers incorrect.

Comment: Leave it as it is. The variation does not change the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should revise your work. My advice is to apply the [Sandwich Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement) in a different way.

Note that the given limit can be written as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{n^2\cdot (\frac{4 \cos(n)}{n^2} - 3)\cdot n^5\cdot(2 - \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^5})}{n^3\cdot (6 + \frac{5\sin(n)}{n^2})\cdot n^4\cdot (1 + \frac{2}{n})^4}$$
Simplify the powers of $n$ and recall that, just by the Sandwich Theorem, if $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n$ is bounded then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n\cdot b_n)=0$.

What is the final answer?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So if we just get rid of the infitesimals the answer is $\frac{-6}{6} = -1$?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Factoring out the main powers of $n$ is the key point.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand.

Comment: @LeonVladimirov Thanks for appreciating.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I just noticed that I wrote the wrong LaTeX formula. The limit I actually have is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4 \cos(n) - 3n)^2(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}$. Would the answer in this case be $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Just using the same approach the limit is $(-3)^2\cdot 2/6$.

Comment: If I apply the Sandwich Theorem to the whole expression I get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4*(-1) - 3n)^2}{6n^2 + 5\sin(n)} = \frac{3}{2}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4*(1) - 3n)^2}{6n^2 + 5\sin(n)} = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: You missed a factor $2$ from the numerator.

Comment: No, sorry I made a mistake. You are absolutely correct. Thank you! Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{(-4 - 3n^2)(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}\le \frac{(4 \cos(n) - 3n^2)(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}\le \frac{(4  - 3n^2)(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}$$

and we can conclude by squeeze theorem since for both bounds

$$\frac{(\pm4  - 3n^2)(2n^5 - n^3 + 1)}{(6n^3 + 5n \sin(n))(n + 2)^4)}\sim \frac{-6n^7}{6n^7} = -1$$

as already noticed by RobertZ, in a simpler way, we can directly use the same argument for the original limit.